# como deixar o video sem o fundo transparente?

Tags: css

Estou usando uma transparentbox com videos do youtube dentro dela, como faço pra deixar os videos sem o fundo transparente?

[meu site](http://www.l2afterlife.com)

Comment: O fundo dos videos parecem normais, o que esta semi-opaco é o background do DIV aonde estão localizados os DIVs, se quer deixar em remover o efeito basta trocar rgba por hex ou rgb, exemplo, troque `.transbox { background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); }` por `.transbox { background-color: #ffffff; }`, se bem que acho que não é isto o que você quer. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Vlw Guilherme, o que o Isac sugeriu deu certo. Obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Ah entendi, é que você já havia editado, vou lhe dizer uma coisa, ao invés de links sempre poste o código, meu comentário saiu equivocado porque você já havia "corrigido" seu CSS, então perdeu o sentido, não somos um site de suporte técnico, colocar o código "falho" aqui faz toda a diferença e ainda por cima pode ajudar outros usuários com a mesma duvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendo em conta que o `<div>` do `youtube` está dentro do `<div>` `transbox` a transparência é herdada, e fica no máximo com `0.7`, que é o que tem. Este `<div>` `youtube` pode assim ser mais transparente, mas não mais opaco.

Uma solução simples é aplicar a transparência através da cor de fundo com `rgba`, que recebe os 3 valores de cor e o ultimo para *alpha* que é a opacidade.

Então isto:

```
.transbox {
    ...
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Passa a ficar:

```
.transbox {
    ...
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); //255,255,255 corresponde a branco
}
```

O que faz com que o `<div class="youtube">` que contem o `<iframe>` fique opaco, devido a cor que já tem atribuída sem opacidade.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.